# Rails rubber - cap command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my sample application to Amazon EC2 using Rubber. I'm also following the railscasts episode on Rubber.

So far I've installed the gem, ran the vulcaznize command, and made modifications to rubber.yml file. When I tried to run a Capistrano command (**cap rubber:create_staging**), however, I get the **cap: command not found** error. I've tried to run the **rbenv rehash** command but it again fails and gives me a **rbenv: command not found.**

If you have any idea how to fix this I would appreciate it greatly. In case you want to know, I'm running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

Solved this problem by installing capistrano manually by typing **gem install capistrano** in the console. I find this weird because capistrano should've been automatically installed while installing rubber. Anyway it seems to have solved the problem for now.